# validating string in cakephp 1.3 controller with preg_match "script"

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, cakephp-1.3

How can I find if string contains "script" tag with preg_match,... ? 
I'm trying to avoid/aboard submission if data passed as "script"

```
 $short_status = $this->params['form']['value'];

 $regex = '/^[<script>]$/i'; 
 if(preg_match($regex, $short_status))
 {
 die();
 }
 else
 {
 to process post and save to database,...
```

thanks in advance, 
chris

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Regex: `#</?script[^>]*>#i`.

Test:

```
if(preg_match('#</?script[^>]*>#i', '<script type="text/javascript">')){
    echo 'SCRIPT FOUND';
}else{
    echo 'Baah, nothing';
}
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/aB1iF5) with some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

after all,... here is what works for me:

```
   $short_status = $this->params['form']['value'];
   $regex = '/^<\w+|script|java|javascript|>$/';

       if(preg_match($regex, $short_status))
      {
    die(); // aboard submission
      }

else
{
     // go to submission and save
```

enjoy it,...